# why should I use js regex instead of string methods, or vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, regex, function

For example, I have the string 'ala bala aladin'. Now, if I want to check after word 'aladin', I can do it with both, regex and string functions, like so:

```
if( /aladin/g.test('ala bala aladin') ) { ..... }
```

or

```
if( 'ala bala aladin'.indexOf("aladin") !='-1' ) { ..... }
```

In this case, what is the best way to use? regex or string methods? And why?

Comment: This should be on the programming exchange.

Comment: Comparing to the *string* `-1`? Why?!

Comment: if the result is -1, then it means that 'aladin' is not found in the string

Comment: You should know because you're writing JavaScript code, presumably, and this sort of thing is important. The result is the *number* `-1` if not found. Not a string.

Comment: Regular expressions are much more powerful than simple substring matches. Given a simple example like the one you provided there will not be a perceptible difference in performance to the user. If you have much larger strings to search or more complex search expressions then you will want to use regular expressions.

Comment: well I know that, but is there any other bad 'practice' to avoid in this case? for me, is more comfortable to use regex, but It could be for example, the time of processing, I don`t know...

Comment: yeas, sorry for comparing with a string, it was a mistake, it is integer, agree :)

Comment: Regex or substring find, that is the question. Some one will post simple analogs and get 5,000 votes - wait and see.

Comment: well it is not really opinion based if you don`t have a solid argument, isn't?

Comment: BTW, I'm here for learning from 'the best', not for giving votes, I`m doing that as a thanks reply :)

Comment: None of these answers or comments explain what/how/when regex would overpower any combination of string operations. It doesn't have to be a complex regex, can be very simple with an assertion, and whoosh you get power. If you fall into the trap of not using what you will eventually need to, it could be a problem

Comment: I don`t know how many of the readers understood that my comparison between regex and str methods was only for those type of simple operations..Just for this case I was interested, and what I found out was that if is not about performance, I can really choose what I want to use....If is not correct, then you can give it a try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either will get you a result just fine.  For simple strings, a regex is likely slower just because a regular expression is a language of its own and the matching code is not as simple as `.indexOf()`.  So, if you just have a straight string with no special regex characters involved, then `.indexOf()` is likely faster.

But, as with all performance issues, if you really care about performance, then you must measure your particular situation in your relevant browsers to be sure.  And, you generally should not favor a solution purely for performance until you know you actually have a material performance issue to worry about.

My guiding principle is to keep my code as simple as possible to solve the desired problem.  For that, my choice is to use `.indexOf()` if I'm just doing a straight string search and to use a regex when I actually need to take advantage of regex features.  But `.test()` is pretty simple too so there really is no wrong answer here.

Go with what you think is the most readable.

---

FYI, here's a quick jsperf to look at the performance difference.  Bigger difference in Firefox (2x).  Chrome and IE have less of a difference.

The operation is overall fast enough (we're talking millions of operations per second) that the difference is unlikely to be noticeable in practice unless this operation is in a tight loop in which case, the creation of the regex object should be outside the loop anyway which changes to a different case to test.

http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof919

[image]

Comment: Added link and graph for a performance test.

Comment: wooow, on firefox 39 it is really a big difference!

Comment: well documented answer, my bad I haven`t choose it as the best :D

Comment: Keep in mind we're talking about the difference between six million *per second* and twenty. If you're calling this less than a million times, this is irrelevant. If you are calling it a million times you probably have an algorithmic problem.

Answer (score 4):

In general, RegEx is going to be ever so slightly slower than string operations. But unless you're using this in a really big loop or doing something where performance is really important, the best version to use is the one that makes the most sense to you and is the most readable.

Comment: but is out there a "chance" for others to see my code and say: "Ooo, why regex here? It should not be done with it", or something like that? I mean it is room for bad "code design"? of course, if is not about performance

Comment: Best practice is to use the most readable way (unless performance is really important or you're doing a lot of iterations). So generally, as long as you stick to that rule, your code should meet most people's standards for "good code".

Answer (score 2):

If you can solve without regex, do without regex.

> Regular expressions are extremely powerful, but they are not the
>   correct solution for every problem. You should learn enough about them
>   to know when they are appropriate, when they will solve your problems,
>   and when they will cause more problems than they solve.
>
> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll
>   use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.
>
> --Jamie Zawinski, in comp.emacs.xemacs

http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/summary.html

Comment: This substring `You should learn enough about them` tell's you he's a crackpot.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things you might want to consider here. Is performance important? Is the string well-defined? Is case-sensitivity an issue? Will there be optional characters in the string?

The `indexOf()` method is fast but not very flexible, so it can only really test vs. exact matches. It can't tell you how many times it matched, just where.

If you're testing vs. a specific string, use a regular expression by default. That way you can always add customization later, like:

```
/aladin/i.test(...) // Test in a case-insensitive manner
/aladd?in/i.test(...) // Allow "aladdin" as well
```

User input is seldom neat and tidy. If you learn how to use regular expressions effectively you can cover a lot of crazy edge cases quite neatly.

If you absolutely need speed, or position information, `indexOf()` has you covered. I'd only be concerned about speed if you run this thing *literally* a million times in a row. For anything less than that the difference will be immeasurable.

Comment: well, yeah, indexOf its limited, my question was only for checking simple things, like this one, so I was also thinking at something else, other than performance, like: it is good or bad to use for a "clean code"

Comment: That's why I'm showing here how even simple things can have reasonable nuances.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use regex from a readability standpoint. It's easier to understand what is going on when using regex instead of comparing a string to an int.

Comment: I think you are perhaps the only person on Earth who has ever suggested regex because it is more readable. I love regex, but readability is most assuredly NOT one of its strong suits. A former colleague of mine always used to remark that a regex looks as though someone held down the shift key then banged on the number keys over and over producing all sorts of random symbols.

Comment: I just don't like comparing strings to ints. That just doesn't make sense to me. Doing regex on strings makes more sense.

Comment: Musical notation makes no sense to most people, but to many it's perfectly readable. Regular expressions are no different. Any sufficiently complicated regular expression will almost always be easier to read than the equivalent long-form code, which will be full of branches, duplication, and confusion. Learning regular expressions is an essential programming skill, they have applicability in virtually every language with almost exactly the same notation.

Comment: lol, so funny, yes it it so weird, at first look, but in this case, I think is not so hard to read...